# Tradingview Pinescript to Python Conversion

Tags: python, pine-script

I've been trying to convert the following Pinescript to Python without much success. I've been able to convert most of it but where I'm getting stuck is snippet surrounded by the "***" below. I've tried picking it apart line by line and I tried different permutations in Python and I can't get it to work fully. Has anyone attempted something similar? This is the original link

https://www.tradingview.com/script/n8AGnIZd-Divergence-for-Many-Indicators-v4/

**Pinescript Code**

```
positive_regular_positive_hidden_divergence(src, cond)=>
    divlen = 0
    prsc = source == "Close" ? close : low
    // if indicators higher than last value and close price is higher than las close 
    if dontconfirm or src > src[1] or close > close[1]
        startpoint = dontconfirm ? 0 : 1 // don't check last candle
        // we search last 15 PPs
        for x = 0 to maxpp - 1
            len = bar_index - array.get(pl_positions, x) + prd
            // if we reach non valued array element or arrived 101. or previous bars then we don't search more
            if array.get(pl_positions, x) == 0 or len > maxbars
                break
            if len > 5 and 
               ((cond == 1 and src[startpoint] > src[len] and prsc[startpoint] < nz(array.get(pl_vals, x))) or
               (cond == 2 and src[startpoint] < src[len] and prsc[startpoint] > nz(array.get(pl_vals, x))))
                slope1 = (src[startpoint] - src[len]) / (len - startpoint)
                virtual_line1 = src[startpoint] - slope1
                slope2 = (close[startpoint] - close[len]) / (len - startpoint)
                virtual_line2 = close[startpoint] - slope2
                arrived = true
                ***for y = 1 + startpoint to len - 1
                    if src[y] < virtual_line1 or nz(close[y]) < virtual_line2
                        arrived := false
                        break
                    virtual_line1 := virtual_line1 - slope1
                    virtual_line2 := virtual_line2 - slope2
                
                if arrived
                    divlen := len
                    break***
    divlen
```

Answer (score 4):

This was a pain but I figured it out. The looping construct was exactly what it looks like. The issues were in my original code. the below works fine but is slow. Can anyone suggest a faster looping mechanism?

```
    for idx in df.index:
        try:
            for y in range(2,int(df['len'][idx])):
                if df['calcinner'][idx] == 1:
                    if ((df[metric][idx - y] < df['vline1'][idx]) | (df['ha_close'][idx - y] < df['vline2'][idx]))==True:
                        df['arrived'][idx] = 0
                        break
                        
                    df['vline1'][idx] = df['vline1'][idx] - df['slope1'][idx]
                    df['vline2'][idx] = df['vline2'][idx] - df['slope2'][idx]

            if df['calcinner'][idx] == 1 & df['arrived'][idx] == 1:
                df['diverge'][idx] = df['diverge'][idx] + df['len'][idx] 

        except:
            print('skip this line')
```